# Limit number of displaying alerts

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to limit how many alerts can be displayed at one time? Or is there a way to check how many alerts are presented on the screen?

Comment: do you mean system notifications?  Or app-generated alerts?

Comment: app-generated alerts

Comment: please show the code you are using to generate the alerts

Comment: `await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");`

Comment: there is no built in way to track or limit them.  They are generated by your code, so you should be able to track them manually if you want

Answer (score 0):

> If you mean `await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");`

If the code is called multiple times in a short time, you need to all the alerts will show once time in the screen of iOS device.(*Cover it one by one*)

And there is no way to track or limit them. You only can control their counts when coding.

For example, using buttn click event to invoke it, one click event results one alert

```
int alertCount = 0;

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(alertCount == 0)
    {
      await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
      alertCount++;
    }else{
      alertCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you reset the count? The problem would arise only when you dont await the `DisplayAlert` otherwise you wouldn't be able to display the second until action is taken on first DisplayAlert

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi You can add some logics inside the method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi And there is a mistake that the phenomenon for iOS and Android is the same. I also update it in answer. You can explain more information about the scene what your needs, it will be helpful to check how to achieve that. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer) and vote it up, it will help others who have similar issue.